# Type mismatch in making a new map. Required (NotInferredA, NotInferredB) , found: String

Tags: scala

I'm trying to return a map of Strings to Doubles, but I keep on getting a type mismatch. I've used the `map.head._1` functionality before to make get values so I don't know why it isn't working.

```
  if (someCondition){
      return Map(key, returnedFuncvalue)
    }
    else {
      val shortMap = Map(propMap.head._1, propMap.head._2)
}
```

IntelliJ gives me this error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: (String, Double)
      return Map(key, returnedFuncvalue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that it should be

```
Map(key -> returnedFuncvalue)
```

The `Map` constructor takes a list of `key`/`value` tuples but you are passing the key and value as separate parameters.

Also note that `return` is not a good idea here (it doesn't work the way you think it does) and avoiding `var` is a good idea.

Taking the `head` of a `Map` is also a bad idea because a `Map` is not ordered so this could return any value in the `Map`.